# How can I use viewModel with parameters in test

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockito, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel to which I inject parameters using Hilt.

```
@HiltViewModel
class ShoppingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val addIngredientUseCase: AddIngredientUseCase,
    private val getIngredientsToBuyUseCase: GetIngredientsToBuyUseCase,
    private val getLastBoughtIngredientsUseCase: GetLastBoughtIngedientsUseCase,
    private val updateIngredientUseCase: UpdateIngredientUseCase,
    private val deleteLastIngredientsUseCase: DeleteLastIngredientsUseCase
) : ViewModel() {...}
```

In the main activity, I have no problem instantiating it:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val shoppingViewModel: ShoppingViewModel by viewModels()

    [...]
}
```

When it comes to testing, I can't instantiate it. How should I go about doing it?

I tried with:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ShoppingViewModelTest() {


    @Mock
    lateinit var addIngredientUseCase: AddIngredientUseCase

    @Mock
    lateinit var updateIngredientUseCase: UpdateIngredientUseCase

    @Mock
    lateinit var deleteLastIngredientsUseCase: DeleteLastIngredientsUseCase

    @Mock
    lateinit var getIngredientsToBuyUseCase: GetIngredientsToBuyUseCase

    @Mock
    lateinit var getLastIngredientsUseCase: GetLastBoughtIngedientsUseCase

    private lateinit var shoppingViewModel: ShoppingViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUP(){
        shoppingViewModel = ShoppingViewModel(addIngredientUseCase,getIngredientsToBuyUseCase,getLastIngredientsUseCase,updateIngredientUseCase,deleteLastIngredientsUseCase)
    }

    @Test
    fun showDialogChangeTest(){

    }
}
```

But i don't know how to initialize the lateinit propierties. What should I do as every useCase has its arguments that I should initialize to

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the oficial [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing).
I have created the class

```
class CustomTestRunner:AndroidJUnitRunner() {

override fun newApplication(
    cl: ClassLoader?,
    className: String?,
    context: Context?
): Application {
    return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
}
```

And added the following lines to the build.gradle file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    // Replace com.example.android.dagger with your class path.
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.android.dagger.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}
```

For the test I used the HiltAndroidTest annotation that allowed me the injection of parameters (I have used dagger hilt all along the progect) as follows:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ShoppingViewModelTest() {

@get:Rule
var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@Inject
lateinit var addIngredientUseCase: AddIngredientUseCase

@Inject
lateinit var updateIngredientUseCase: UpdateIngredientUseCase

@Inject
lateinit var deleteLastIngredientsUseCase: DeleteLastIngredientsUseCase

@Inject
lateinit var getIngredientsToBuyUseCase: GetIngredientsToBuyUseCase

@Inject
lateinit var getLastIngredientsUseCase: GetLastBoughtIngedientsUseCase

private lateinit var shoppingViewModel:ShoppingViewModel


@Before
fun init(){
    hiltRule.inject()
    shoppingViewModel = ShoppingViewModel(addIngredientUseCase,getIngredientsToBuyUseCase,getLastIngredientsUseCase,updateIngredientUseCase,deleteLastIngredientsUseCase)
    }
}
```